# Pagination links load only load once time

Tags: laravel-5

How load div only or data instead of load whole page while using pagination in laravel?
on every click pagination get data from database again. I  want paginate pick data only at once and then proceed.
Any expert please!!!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using DataTables for that. But it will mostly depend on your project, preferences, knowledge...

https://datatables.net/

Comment: I just want to use it for online quiz Application